# Specify Rails versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed Rails 2.2.3 in Ubuntu 10.04 through the repository. After found that it is not the newest version, I decided to install it through RubyGems. So how do I specify which Rails version to use when I start a project?

Comment: [Choosing your application's version of Rail](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/03/choosing-your-applications-ver.html)

Answer (score 1):

After you have created your project, modify the following statement in config/environment.rb

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.1.1' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```